# So… is prostitution in Canada legal or not?

Tags: canada, prostitution

I'm confused, is prostitution in Canada legal or not?

I've been looking, but have up till now only gotten mixed messages when it comes to it's legality; just a jumble of legislative actions, court rulings, and public statements all wrapped in a confusing multi-year timeline and many vague/assuming articles in the press.

So... is it? And what are the nuances of it?

Comment: It's sometimes called the "Swedish model" or the "Nordic model": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prostitution_in_Sweden#Exporting_the_model

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Yes and No

Selling your own body for sex is legal. Buying sex is illegal. Therefore the transaction as a whole is legal on the part of the seller and illegal on the part of the buyer.

See [Prostitution in Canada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prostitution_in_Canada) and [Prostitution law in Canada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prostitution_law_in_Canada).

If you think this is odd, you are not alone '... one judge referring to the laws as "Alice-in-Wonderland" and the Chief Justice of the Supreme Court referred to the situation as "bizarre"'.

In the circumstances, although I know of no case law on this, it would appear that any contract for prostitution would be void for illegality. Presumably, to enforce payment for services rendered the service provider would need to pursue a quantum meruit claim in equity.

Comment: How enforced is the law? Are police mandated to hunt buyers down? Or could you get away with it if you're careful in hiding your "customer(s)"?

Comment: @Tirous I imagine that would differ from location to location and time to time. Police have discretion as to what crimes they investigate and what they don't, prosecutors likewise.

Comment: Wow, that is weird!  If the situation was something like that in the US, I'd think that selling sex would still be indirectly illegal as it'd qualify as a conspiracy to commit a crime, specifically by assisting the buyer in their intent to commit the crime of buying sex.  I guess that the law doesn't work that way in Canada?  This is, prostitutes can't be held responsible for assisting (or even inciting) their clients to commit the crime of buying their services?

Comment: I don't find it weird. Criminalising the buyer allows for prostitutes that want to leave to seek help from authorities without fearing prosecution. It's a model that has been used in Scandinavia too.

Comment: It's similar spirit to penalizing selling drugs, so the state can take down dealers, without penalizing (or penalizing less) buying and taking drugs, so the state can help addicts get clean. Look at "possession with intent to distribute" vs mere "possession".

Comment: Wow... *"quantum meruit claim in equity"* is hands down the smartest thing I've ever read  Now back to the answer, why do you think this is the case? Is it because they don't *really* want to legalise prostitution?

Comment: @Nat on a similar idea, in Italy selling alcohol to minors is forbidden, but minors do not get prosecuted for buying it. I've been told that this is not the case in the USA and I personally find *that* to be extremely weird.

Comment: "If you think this is odd, you are not alone" - I do not find it weird at all, but pretty sensible. To make the offer illegal would harm those that actually *are* harmed by the act of prostitiution even more. To legalize the consumption would open doors for really bad stuff (like selling someone *else*, child stuff etc.). To forbid it completely would be totally unfeasible (compare prohibition in the U.S.). As it stands now, any (real) victim has the power of the legalities behind them, and no (real) offender can say "but it was just legal prostitiution".

Comment: "As it stands now, any (real) victim has the power of the legalities behind them, and no (real) offender can say "but it was just legal prostitiution". " - doesn't this depend on a circular definition, that if someone does not have sex with you and instead leaves you handcuffed to the bed and runs off with your wallet you are not a "real victim" (or, for a less extreme case, walks off with the payment itself, leaving you with no recourse because it was either a gift or an illegal transaction) because your part in the intended transaction was illegal?

Comment: @Nat: Crimes that require two persons by the nature of the crime don't count as "conspiracy". Examples would be prostitution where illegal, or bribing a police officer.

Comment: @Mango Historically in Canada prostitution itself in Canada wasn't illegal. Neither the prostitute or the client could be prosecuted for the act of buying or selling sex. Instead everything around prostitution was made illegal (and for the most part still is), communicating/soliciting prostitution, living off the affairs of a prostitute, operating a common bawdy house were the crimes prostitutes (and their pimps and sometimes johns, were prosecuted for). This was changed when the old law was struct downs as unconstitutional.

Comment: @JamesK It seems logically inconsistent to make the participation in a crime not a crime.  I mean, I definitely appreciate the intent to allow sex workers to get help when/if that's the motive, but it'd seem like that could be done under a more sensible mechanism, e.g. a law that instantly grants immunity to any sex worker as soon as they attempt to seek help of any sort.  But, the blanket immunity here seems to apply to those who aren't even interested in seeking help.

Comment: A reference should be provided for the quantum meruit suggestion. I doubt that equitable relief would be granted to enforce a contract that is void for illegality.